# --num-procs option in bokeh load balancing policy

Tags: load, bokeh, tornado, scaling

In the documentation it suggests that the forking is done in the underlying Tornado Server although i was trying to figure out what the load balancing policy is if there are muliple processes.
Say there are 3 process running (using bokeh serve --num-procs 3) then is there a chance that 3 requests coming in get directed to just one of those and other two processes remain fairly idle ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Bokeh is not doing anything special and is just using Tornado's multi-process mode, there is nothing that guarantees load will be balanced across the processes and significant imbalances are possible. This includes having all 3 connections going to one process while the other two remain idle. As traffic increases it becomes less likely to have this kind of 100/0 split, but it's very common for the busiest process to have at least twice as many connections as the least busy.

There's no real "load balancing policy" here - when a connection comes in, the kernel will wake up all three processes, and whichever one executes its `accept` system call first gets the connection. Often that means that a process that already has a request gets the next one because it's already scheduled and cached (on the other hand, sometimes that process is busy working on a previous request and can't accept the new one right away).

I've heard that the `SO_REUSEPORT` option makes this better, but haven't verified this myself.